# Raspberry PI 4 hardware registers access

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi4

I'm working on an embedded Linux training with Raspberry PI 4B and in order to create I2C bus driver I need to access hardware registers. The problem is when I try to read any of them I get "Unhandled fault: unknown 3 (0x203) at 0xf08c5000".

Here is the code I'm using to read register:

```
void i2cHandler_init(void)
{
    const u32 rpiPeriphBase = 0xfe000000;
    const u32 rpiGpioOffset = 0x200000;

    const void *rpiGpioAddress = rpiPeriphBase + rpiGpioOffset;

    __iomem u32 *ioMemory;
    ioMemory = ioremap(rpiGpioAddress, 0x40 * 8);

    pr_info("%s: rpiGpioAddress = 0x%x\r\n", __func__, rpiGpioAddress);
    pr_info("%s: ioMemory = 0x%x\r\n", __func__, ioMemory);
    pr_info("%s: Register value = 0x%x\r\n", __func__, readl(ioMemory));

    if(ioMemory != NULL)
        iounmap(ioMemory);
}
```

Yes, I'm trying to read GPIO GPFSEL0 register here, but changing offset to read I2C Control register changes nothing.
Kernel log output looks like this:

```
[ 1467.677279] i2cHandler_init: rpiGpioAddress = 0xfe200000
[ 1467.677289] i2cHandler_init: ioMemory = 0xf08c5000
[ 1467.677308] 8<--- cut here ---
[ 1467.677325] Unhandled fault: unknown 3 (0x203) at 0xf08c5000
[ 1467.677340] pgd = f812a8c9
[ 1467.677353] [f08c5000] *pgd=80000000007003, *pmd=2ff5b003, *pte=c00ffffe200713
[ 1467.677385] Internal error: : 203 [#1] SMP ARM
[ 1467.677400] Modules linked in: rpi_driver_I2C(O+) rfcomm cmac algif_hash aes_arm_bs crypto_simd cryptd algif_skcipher af_alg bnep hci_uart btbcm bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc spidev snd_soc_hdmi_codec 8021q garp stp llc brcmfmac brcmutil v3d cfg80211 gpu_sched rfkill raspberrypi_hwmon i2c_brcmstb vc4 spi_bcm2835 cec bcm2835_codec(C) bcm2835_v4l2(C) bcm2835_isp(C) v4l2_mem2mem bcm2835_mmal_vchiq(C) videobuf2_dma_contig videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common vc_sm_cma(C) drm_kms_helper videodev snd_bcm2835(C) snd_soc_core mc snd_compress snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm rpivid_mem snd_timer snd syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops uio_pdrv_genirq uio nvmem_rmem i2c_dev drm drm_panel_orientation_quirks backlight fuse ip_tables x_tables ipv6 [last unloaded: rpi_driver_I2C]
[ 1467.677744] CPU: 0 PID: 2059 Comm: insmod Tainted: G         C O      5.15.32-v7l+ #1538
[ 1467.677764] Hardware name: BCM2711
[ 1467.677775] PC is at i2cHandler_init+0xc4/0x178 [rpi_driver_I2C]
[ 1467.677808] LR is at irq_work_queue+0x14/0x2c
[ 1467.677833] pc : [<bf3fe464>]    lr : [<c0358054>]    psr: 60000013
[ 1467.677846] sp : c3e57d68  ip : 00000000  fp : c3e57d7c
[ 1467.677859] r10: c1205048  r9 : bf400380  r8 : 00000000
[ 1467.677871] r7 : 00000002  r6 : bf3fe5a8  r5 : c1205048  r4 : f08c5000
[ 1467.677884] r3 : 3391a86e  r2 : 3391a86e  r1 : 00000027  r0 : 00000029
[ 1467.677898] Flags: nZCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
[ 1467.677914] Control: 30c5383d  Table: 041e1e40  DAC: fffffffd
[ 1467.677926] Register r0 information: non-paged memory
[ 1467.677943] Register r1 information: non-paged memory
[ 1467.677958] Register r2 information: non-paged memory
[ 1467.677973] Register r3 information: non-paged memory
[ 1467.677988] Register r4 information: 0-page vmalloc region starting at 0xf08c5000 allocated at i2cHandler_init+0x80/0x178 [rpi_driver_I2C]
[ 1467.678024] Register r5 information: non-slab/vmalloc memory
[ 1467.678041] Register r6 information: 4-page vmalloc region starting at 0xbf3fe000 allocated at load_module+0xb94/0x2840
[ 1467.678069] Register r7 information: non-paged memory
[ 1467.678084] Register r8 information: NULL pointer
[ 1467.678099] Register r9 information: 4-page vmalloc region starting at 0xbf3fe000 allocated at load_module+0xb94/0x2840
[ 1467.678124] Register r10 information: non-slab/vmalloc memory
[ 1467.678140] Register r11 information: non-slab/vmalloc memory
[ 1467.678155] Register r12 information: NULL pointer
[ 1467.678170] Process insmod (pid: 2059, stack limit = 0x91bbcd6e)
[ 1467.678185] Stack: (0xc3e57d68 to 0xc3e58000)
[ 1467.678199] 7d60:                   bf400380 c1205048 c3e57d8c c3e57d80 bf3fe5fc bf3fe3ac
[ 1467.678217] 7d80: c3e57d9c c3e57d90 bf3fe5cc bf3fe5e4 c3e57e14 c3e57da0 c02021c4 bf3fe5b4
[ 1467.678234] 7da0: c0439ca0 c0bd5bf4 c1401180 00000000 c3e57dd4 c3e57dc0 c0bd5bf4 c029f244
[ 1467.678251] 7dc0: c1401180 c043ade4 c3e57e14 c3e57dd8 c043ade4 c03f4518 c041c20c c043997c
[ 1467.678269] 7de0: 00000008 c02d056c f097d000 3391a86e 00000002 bf400380 00000002 c3c36d80
[ 1467.678286] 7e00: 00000002 c4ad01c8 c3e57e3c c3e57e18 c02d058c c0202180 c3e57e3c c3e57e28
[ 1467.678303] 7e20: c041c394 c3e57f30 00000002 c4ad0180 c3e57f14 c3e57e40 c02d2dac c02d0544
[ 1467.678320] 7e40: bf40038c 00007fff bf400380 c02cf240 c1205048 c0e3b448 c0e3b460 c0e3b3f0
[ 1467.678337] 7e60: bf0c609a c0e3b4b0 c0c03df0 c3e57f30 bf400594 c4dc6418 bf4003c8 c4ad0188
[ 1467.678354] 7e80: c0e3afcc 00000001 00000000 c0efea84 c0ee67d0 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 1467.678371] 7ea0: 00000000 00000000 6e72656b 00006c65 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 1467.678388] 7ec0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 1467.678405] 7ee0: 00000000 3391a86e c3e57f2c c1205048 00000000 0002de04 00000003 c0200244
[ 1467.678423] 7f00: c3e56000 0000017b c3e57fa4 c3e57f18 c02d33b0 c02d0900 c3e57f2c 7fffffff
[ 1467.678439] 7f20: 00000000 00000002 c3e57f24 f097d000 f097db9e f097e5c0 f097d000 000033ac
[ 1467.678456] 7f40: f097ff9c f097fea8 f097f3a0 00003000 000036e0 00002018 00003aab 00000000
[ 1467.678474] 7f60: 00000000 00000000 00002008 00000017 00000018 00000010 0000000d 0000000a
[ 1467.678491] 7f80: 00000000 3391a86e 00000000 00000002 f9957800 0000017b 00000000 c3e57fa8
[ 1467.678508] 7fa0: c0200040 c02d32f4 00000000 00000002 00000003 0002de04 00000000 b6f68074
[ 1467.678535] 7fc0: 00000000 00000002 f9957800 0000017b 00e9acc8 00000002 bee367d4 00000000
[ 1467.678554] 7fe0: bee36600 bee365f0 00023bc0 b6c459e0 60000010 00000003 00000000 00000000
[ 1467.678568] Backtrace:
[ 1467.678582] [<bf3fe3a0>] (i2cHandler_init [rpi_driver_I2C]) from [<bf3fe5fc>] (mainCycle_init+0x24/0x38 [rpi_driver_I2C])
[ 1467.678632]  r5:c1205048 r4:bf400380
[ 1467.678643] [<bf3fe5d8>] (mainCycle_init [rpi_driver_I2C]) from [<bf3fe5cc>] (init_module+0x24/0x30 [rpi_driver_I2C])
[ 1467.678687] [<bf3fe5a8>] (init_module [rpi_driver_I2C]) from [<c02021c4>] (do_one_initcall+0x50/0x244)
[ 1467.678726] [<c0202174>] (do_one_initcall) from [<c02d058c>] (do_init_module+0x54/0x23c)
[ 1467.678760]  r8:c4ad01c8 r7:00000002 r6:c3c36d80 r5:00000002 r4:bf400380
[ 1467.678776] [<c02d0538>] (do_init_module) from [<c02d2dac>] (load_module+0x24b8/0x2840)
[ 1467.678807]  r6:c4ad0180 r5:00000002 r4:c3e57f30
[ 1467.678824] [<c02d08f4>] (load_module) from [<c02d33b0>] (sys_finit_module+0xc8/0xfc)
[ 1467.678857]  r10:0000017b r9:c3e56000 r8:c0200244 r7:00000003 r6:0002de04 r5:00000000
[ 1467.678876]  r4:c1205048
[ 1467.678892] [<c02d32e8>] (sys_finit_module) from [<c0200040>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x1c)
[ 1467.678925] Exception stack(0xc3e57fa8 to 0xc3e57ff0)
[ 1467.678943] 7fa0:                   00000000 00000002 00000003 0002de04 00000000 b6f68074
[ 1467.678969] 7fc0: 00000000 00000002 f9957800 0000017b 00e9acc8 00000002 bee367d4 00000000
[ 1467.678986] 7fe0: bee36600 bee365f0 00023bc0 b6c459e0
[ 1467.679007]  r7:0000017b r6:f9957800 r5:00000002 r4:00000000
[ 1467.679030] Code: e1a02004 e30f0360 e34b0f3f eb5f37d6 (e5942000)
[ 1467.679052] ---[ end trace b887a2abb18bba14 ]---
```

Also I'm sure peripherals base address is correct because output of "sudo cat /proc/iomem" looks like this:

```
00000000-3b3fffff : System RAM
  00008000-00ffffff : Kernel code
  01200000-013ef203 : Kernel data
40000000-7fffffff : System RAM
fd500000-fd50930f : fd500000.pcie pcie@7d500000
fd580000-fd58ffff : fd580000.ethernet ethernet@7d580000
  fd580e14-fd580e1c : unimac-mdio.-19
fe004000-fe00401f : fe004000.txp txp@7e004000
fe007000-fe007aff : fe007000.dma dma@7e007000
fe007b00-fe007eff : fe007b00.dma dma@7e007b00
fe00a000-fe00a023 : fe100000.watchdog watchdog@7e100000
fe00b840-fe00b87b : fe00b840.mailbox mailbox@7e00b840
fe00b880-fe00b8bf : fe00b880.mailbox mailbox@7e00b880
fe100000-fe100113 : fe100000.watchdog watchdog@7e100000
fe101000-fe102fff : fe101000.cprman cprman@7e101000
fe104000-fe104027 : fe104000.rng rng@7e104000
**fe200000-fe2000b3 : fe200000.gpio gpio@7e200000**
fe201000-fe2011ff : serial@7e201000
  fe201000-fe2011ff : fe201000.serial serial@7e201000
fe204000-fe2041ff : fe204000.spi spi@7e204000
fe206000-fe2060ff : fe206000.pixelvalve pixelvalve@7e206000
fe207000-fe2070ff : fe207000.pixelvalve pixelvalve@7e207000
fe20a000-fe20a0ff : fe20a000.pixelvalve pixelvalve@7e20a000
fe215000-fe215007 : fe215000.aux aux@7e215000
fe216000-fe2160ff : fe216000.pixelvalve pixelvalve@7e216000
fe300000-fe3000ff : fe300000.mmcnr mmcnr@7e300000
fe340000-fe3400ff : fe340000.mmc mmc@7e340000
fe400000-fe407fff : fe400000.hvs hvs@7e400000
fec00000-fec03fff : fec00000.v3d hub
fec04000-fec07fff : fec00000.v3d core0
fec11000-fec1101f : fe100000.watchdog watchdog@7e100000
fec12000-fec120ff : fec12000.pixelvalve pixelvalve@7ec12000
fef00000-fef0000f : fef00000.clock clock@7ef00000
fef00b00-fef00dff : fef04500.i2c auto-i2c
fef04500-fef045ff : fef04500.i2c bsc
fef05b00-fef05dff : fef09500.i2c auto-i2c
fef09500-fef095ff : fef09500.i2c bsc
600000000-63fffffff : pcie@7d500000
  600000000-6000fffff : PCI Bus 0000:01
    600000000-600000fff : 0000:01:00.0
      600000000-600000fff : xhci-hcd
```

Raspbeerry PI works under the Raspbian OS 32-bit version. Kernel version is 5.15.32-v7l+.
I tried different base addresses found from different sources:

- 0x20000000 - ioremap returns 0.
- 0x3e000000 - ioremap works, no errors, but values there make no sense and writing with this base address leads to no reaction at all.
- 0x7e000000 - ioremap returns 0.
- 0x7e000000 without ioremap - error "Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ...".

According to different forums topics and examples my piece of code should just work, but it is not, so I'm out of ideas right now. Does anyone have any thoughts? Is this my error or something else is wrong?

Comment: You are trying to read a device register which is under use of driver. Note, Linux OS is multi-tasking, racing with existing driver is not a good idea to begin with. You need to disable GPIO driver first before poking its registers.

Comment: Thank you, @0andriy. That was my guess too, but I tried to read BSC0 registers (I2C controller, physical address 0x7e205000) and result was the same. I don't see any driver claiming this address. Also I tried to read PWM RNG1 register just now and result is the same (physical address is 0x7e20c010, no driver working with this peripheral, address is not registered).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. Nothing seems wrong with my code, 64-bit OS helped.
I didn't actually install 64-bit system, I added "arm_64bit=1" to my /boot/config.txt and updated all packages, because this was just for testing purposes, but this worked.